# ads not showing up-Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, ads, parameters

I am trying to put ads in my app but I couldn't manage setting layout file. 
The layout file is as follows

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

tools:context=".PhotoEffectMainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/mainbg" >

<!-- preview layout starts -->

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/previewlayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

 <ImageView android:id="@+id/previewbutton"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:background="@drawable/preview"/>

 </LinearLayout>

<!--  preview layout ends -->

 <!-- effect layout starts -->
 <LinearLayout 
     android:id="@+id/effectlayout"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_below="@id/previewlayout">

     <!--  first layout-->

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/effectbutton"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="left" >

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/effect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

   </LinearLayout>

     <!-- first layout ends -->

     <!-- second layout starts -->


      <LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:gravity="right"
>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" > 

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mygallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:visibility="invisible"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

      <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />

       <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />
        <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />

         <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />

          <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />

           <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   />

            <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />

             <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />

              <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />

               <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

 />

                <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   />

                 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />


    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

      <!-- second layout ends -->

   </LinearLayout>

 <!-- effect layout ends -->
 <!-- view layout starts -->
 <LinearLayout 
     android:id="@+id/viewlayout"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/effectlayout">



      <com.appbasic.imageeditor.MyView
android:id="@+id/drawView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
/>


 </LinearLayout>

 <!-- view layout ends -->
 <!-- adlayout starts -->
 <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/adlayout"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/viewlayout" >


     <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/banner"  
         />

 </LinearLayout>

 <!--  ad layout ends  -->



</LinearLayout>
```

I am also trying to give sizes programmatically.

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams p4=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(450*screenWidth/480, 40*screenHeight/800); 

        previewlayout.setLayoutParams(p4); 

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p6=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(460*screenWidth/480, 70*screenHeight/800); 

        effectlayout.setLayoutParams(p6);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p3=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(360*screenWidth/480, 70*screenHeight/800); 

        adlayout.setLayoutParams(p3); 

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p5=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(475*screenWidth/480, (screenHeight)-(previewlayout.getHeight()+effectlayout.getHeight()+adlayout.getHeight())*screenHeight/800); 

        viewlayout.setLayoutParams(p5);
```

Please help me with these. I am struggling since two days.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove any padding and margin from your layout as Ads need the full width of screen to display.

Comment: at last solved it using Relative layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by the changing the layout as follows.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

tools:context=".PhotoEffectMainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/mainbg" >

<!-- preview layout starts -->

<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/previewlayout"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">

 <ImageView android:id="@+id/previewbutton"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:background="@drawable/preview"/>

 </LinearLayout>

<!--  preview layout ends -->

 <!-- effect layout starts -->
 <LinearLayout 
 android:id="@+id/effectlayout"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_below="@id/previewlayout">

 <!--  first layout-->

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/effectbutton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="left" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/effect"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 </LinearLayout>

 <!-- first layout ends -->

 <!-- second layout starts -->


  <LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:gravity="right"
 >

<HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" > 

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mygallery"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:visibility="invisible"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

  <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/im1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />

  <ImageView
android:id="@+id/im2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

/>

   <ImageView
android:id="@+id/im3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

/>
    <ImageView
android:id="@+id/im4"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

/>

     <ImageView
android:id="@+id/im5"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

/>

      <ImageView
android:id="@+id/im6"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

/>

       <ImageView
android:id="@+id/im7"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

/>

        <ImageView
android:id="@+id/im8"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

/>

         <ImageView
android:id="@+id/im9"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

/>

          <ImageView
android:id="@+id/im10"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

/>

           <ImageView
android:id="@+id/im11"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

 />

            <ImageView
android:id="@+id/im12"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

/>

             <ImageView
android:id="@+id/im13"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

/>


</LinearLayout>

 </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

  <!-- second layout ends -->

</LinearLayout>

  <!-- effect layout ends -->
  <!-- view layout starts -->
    <LinearLayout 
 android:id="@+id/viewlayout"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@id/effectlayout">



  <com.appbasic.imageeditor.MyView
android:id="@+id/drawView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
/>


 </LinearLayout>

 <!-- view layout ends -->
 <!-- adlayout starts --

 <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/banner"  
     />

 <!--  ad layout ends  -->



 </RelativeLayout>
```